# Python - 'TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int''

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df column that has values ranging from -5 to 10. I want to change values <= -1 to `negative`, all 0 values to `neutral`, and all values >= 1 to `positive`. The code below, however, produces the following error for 'negative'.

```
# Function to change values to labels

test.loc[test['sentiment_score'] > 0, 'sentiment_score'] = 'positive'
test.loc[test['sentiment_score'] == 0, 'sentiment_score'] = 'neutral'
test.loc[test['sentiment_score'] < 0, 'sentiment_score'] = 'negative'

Data:                                  Data After Code:
Index     Sentiment                    Index     Sentiment
 0         2                            0         positive
 1         0                            1         neutral
 2        -3                            2         -3
 3         4                            3         positive
 4        -1                            4         -1
 ...                                    ...
 k         5                            k         positive
```

> File "pandas_libs\ops.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_compare
>    TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int

I assume that this has something to do with the function seeing negative numbers as string rather than float/int, however I've tried the following code to correct this error and it changes nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
test['sentiment_score'] = test['sentiment_score'].astype(float)
test['sentiment_score'] = test['sentiment_score'].apply(pd.as_numeric)
```

Comment: Have you tried `float(test['sentiment_score']) > 0`?

Comment: @Joel I hope not, because that's completely wrong

Comment: Negative numbers are not seen as string. You're doing your replacement in 3 parts. By the time you get to `test.loc[test['sentiment_score'] == 0, 'sentiment_score'] = 'neutral'` you've already added a load of strings to that column from `test.loc[test['sentiment_score'] > 0, 'sentiment_score'] = 'positive'`

Comment: @roganjosh Nice catch!

Comment: Thankyou. So what is the solution, to create 3 columns for each score and then to merge them all at the end?

Comment: I imagine you would be better creating a new column to hold categorical data

Comment: Okay thankyou, do you want to add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: I think Coldspeed might have given you something closer to the initial intended output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As roganjosh pointed out, you're doing your replacement in 3 steps - this is causing a problem because after step 1, you end up with a column of mixed dtypes, so subsequent equality checks start to fail.

You can either assign to a new column, or use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

```
condlist = [
   test['sentiment_score'] > 0,
   test['sentiment_score'] < 0
]
choicelist = ['pos', 'neg']

test['sentiment_score'] = np.select(
   condlist, choicelist, default='neutral')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try your answer: TypeError: select() got multiple values for argument 'default'

Comment: Thanks guys, big help. I ended up using RoganJosh's solution of creating a new column to add categorical data, however this works perfectly as well, and is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to define a custom function:

```
def transform_sentiment(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 'Negative'
    elif x == 0:
        return 'Neutral'
    else:
        return 'Positive'

df['Sentiment_new'] = df['Sentiment'].apply(lambda x: transform_sentiment(x))
```