# Error input output while excuting Python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, syntax

I wrote the following program in Python but I got this error
please guide me

```
age= (input("please inter your age:" ))
if age > 40:
    print ("old")
elif 40>age>=30:
    print ("middle-age")    
elif 30>age>=20:
    print ("yong")
```

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I checked the program several times

Comment: Why Java tag, since code is in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - 'TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249024/python-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances-of-str-and-int)

Answer (score 1):

the `age` variable is of string data type. You need to convert it to int before comparing it using operators like this -

```
age= int(input("please inter your age:" ))
if age > 40:
    print ("old")
elif 40>age>=30:
    print ("middle-age")    
elif 30>age>=20:
    print ("yong")
```

The int() before the input statement will convert the data entered by the user from string to int type.

Answer (score 0):

while doing comparison change the age type to `int`, Since you input age with use of `input` which returns string.

```
age= (input("please inter your age:" ))
if int(age) > 40:
    print ("old")
elif 40>int(age)>=30:
    print ("middle-age")    
elif 30>int(age)>=20:
    print ("yong")
```

This gives you the expected output you want

output:

```
please inter your age:45
old
```